# Error : 'bool QTabWidget::hasHeightForWidth() const' marked 'override', but does not override bool hasHeightForWidth() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to build my qt application in REDHAT 6.5 but getting this error.

ERR CODE :

> ```
> error: bool QTabWidget::hasHeightForWidth() const marked
> ```
>
> 'override', but does not override      bool hasHeightForWidth() const
>   Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

I'm using Qt 5

g++ version 6.3

In my .pro file i've already mentioned to use c++11 version that is

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

i've also tried setting

```
CONFIG += cpp11
```

but still it is throwing the same error. what else i'm missing?

Comment: Show the header files containing the declarations for hasHeightForWidth()

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error. It turned out to be due to a rogue Qt4-style include (in my case, `QtGui/QTabWidget`). Make sure you don't have any includes that are inadvertently pointing at Qt4 headers...

Answer (score 0):

When I included these files, it worked ok.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDialog> //if you are using dialog boxes in this header or cpp file.
```